# Blocking action of CDialog's maximize/minimize button

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using mfc CDialog.  I need to show the close and minimize/maximize button, but they should not close or maximize the dialog.  I have overriden OnClose method and kept the dialog open even if close button is clicked.  But I am unable to block maximize and minimize of the dialog as there doesn't seem to be a OnMaximize method.  Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message, watching for `wParam == SC_MAXIMIZE`.

If you catch the SC_MINIMIZE, you can do what you want and not pass it on to Windows.

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Found this snippet [here.](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t12065-how-override-forms-maximize-button-operation.aspx)

```
const int WM_SYSCOMMAND= 0x0112;
const int SC_MAXIMIZE= 0xF030;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if(m.Msg==WM_SYSCOMMAND)
    {
        if((int)m.WParam==SC_MAXIMIZE)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maximized!!");
            return; // swallow the message
        }
    }
    base.WndProc (ref m);
}
```

Comment: thanks egrunin... It works like a charm... you are a saviour ... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not show at all the minimise/maximise icons i your dialog. You can do that by going to Dialog properties (right vlick on your Dialog Contorol --> Properties), Select Styles pain and unselect 'Minimise Box', 'Maximise Box'.

Comment: yeah thanks, I know that but i need the boxes to be visible... but the actions should not work on them.